# Find all unique columns from a huge(having millions of records and columns)OFS file(without fixed header row) unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Input

```
119764469|14100733//1,k1=v1,k2=v2,STREET:1:1=NY
119764469|14100733//1,k1=v1,k2=v2,k3=v3 
119764469|14100733//1,k1=v1,k4=v4,abc.xyz:1:1=nmb,abc,po.foo:1:1=yu
```

k1 could be any name with alphanumeric with . & : special chars like abc.nm.1:1

Expected output(all unique columns), sorting not required/necessary , it should be super fast

```
k1,k2,STREET:1:1,k3,k4,abc.xyz:1:1
```

My current approach/solution is

```
awk -F',' '{for (i=0; i<=NR; i++) {for(j=1; j<=NF; j++){split($j,a,"="); print a[1];}}}' file.txt | awk '!x[$1]++' | grep -v '|' | sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ | /; ta'
```

It works fine but it is too slow for huge size of file(which could be in MBs or in GBs in size)

NOTE: This is required in data migration, should use basic unix shell commands as production may not allow to have 3rd party utilities.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the outer `for (i=0; i<=NR; i++)` loop. It's redundant - awk processes every record anyway - and makes the awk script run in quadratic time instead of linear.

Comment: If performance is such an issue because you deal with huge files, you could write a tiny C program and compile it on the target machine.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C programs aren't generally faster than awk scripts for tasks like this because awk is highly optimized for this specific task whereas the code people write in C to do the job generally isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure about the speed but give it a try

```
$ cut -d, -f2- file |        # select the key/value pairs
  tr ',' '\n'       |        # split each k=v to its own line
  cut -d= -f1       |        # select only keys
  sort -u           |        # filter uniques
  paste -sd,                 # serialize back to single csv line

abc.xyz:1:1,k1,k2,k3,k4,STREET:1:1
```

I expect it to be faster than `grep` since no regex is involved.

Comment: works great as per the requirement, I have just updated the input data a bit. I don't want 'abc' as my column so I have used 'grep \:' after tr as my expected columns(keys) would have ':' char, I just wanted to know if there's again any alternate to this 'grep \:'?

Comment: Also, what if I need ' | ' as delim instead of ',' like abc.xyz:1:1 | k1 | k2 | k3 | k4 | STREET:1:1

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -o` to grep only the parts you need:

```
grep -o -e '[^=,]\+=[^,]\+' file.txt |awk -F'=' '{print $1}' |sort |uniq |tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/'
>>> abc.xyz:1:1,k1,k2,k3,k4,STREET:1:1
```

(`sort` is needed here because otherwise `uniq` doesn't work)

Comment: sorting not required, and column names could be anything which may have . & : as special chars, OP updated

Comment: @BaajiRao Edited according to new requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the output all on one line:

```
$ awk -F'[,=]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file | sort -u
abc.xyz:1:1
k1
k2
k3
k4
STREET:1:1
```

If you do:

```
$ awk -F'[,=]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file | sort -u |
    awk -v ORS= '{print sep $0; sep=","} END{print RS}'
abc.xyz:1:1,k1,k2,k3,k4,STREET:1:1
```

You could do it all in one awk script but I'm not sure it'll be as efficient as the above or might run into memory issues if/when the array grows to millions of values:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[,=]"; ORS="" }
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        vals[$i]
    }
}
END {
    for (val in vals) {
        print sep val
        sep = ","
    }
    print RS
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
k1,abc.xyz:1:1,k2,k3,k4,STREET:1:1
```